# CentOS 7 pidof -x did not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, apollo

I have one CentOS 7 Server VM. In this VM I have `Apache Apollo` installed

I just created a script given below

```
#!/bin/bash

if pidof -x "apollo" >/dev/null; then
echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
exit 2
fi
```

Using above script I want to check apollo service is running or not. But when i run this script using below command

```
sh filename
```

It gives the output `Apollo MQTT is Stopped` when servce is running.

When I run below command

```
ps -ef | grep apollo
```

It gives the below output

```
root       8647      1  3 10:49 pts/0    00:00:55 java -ea -server -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dapollo.home=/opt/apollo -Dapollo.base=/var/lib/mqtt -classpath /opt/apollo/lib/apollo-boot.jar org.apache.activemq.apollo.boot.Apollo /var/lib/mqtt/lib\;/opt/apollo/lib org.apache.activemq.apollo.cli.Apollo run
root       9426   8233  0 11:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apollo
```

Comment: `pgrep -f apollo >/dev/null`?

Comment: @Cyrus When I use "if pgrep -f apollo >/dev/null; then" it always show me Apollo MQTT is Running. If service is running and stop both cases.

Comment: Stop Apollo and check with `ps -ef | grep apollo`.

Comment: @Cyrus Stop Apollo and check with ps -ef | grep apollo output is "root      12561   8233  0 12:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apollo"

Comment: What happens when you run start/stop the service & run `pgrep -f apollo && echo running || echo stopped` ?

Comment: @anishsane In both cases start/stop apollo output is "Apollo MQTT is Running."

Comment: Off the topic: In order to prevent `grep` from showing up in `ps -ef | grep` output (last line in your output snippet), try this: `ps -ef | grep '[a]pollo'` instead of `ps -ef | grep 'apollo'`. (`grep -v grep` is an ugly approach & not a robust one.)

Comment: Strange. Stop Apollo and please post output of `pgrep -f apollo`.

Comment: After stopping the service, what does `ps -f "$(pgrep -f apollo)"` return?

Comment: @Cyrus Stop Apollo and run "pgrep -f apollo" output is nothing.

Comment: @anishsane where i write "ps -f "$(pgrep -f apollo)"" ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with RHEL 7. Please stop Apollo and post output of `pgrep -f apollo; echo $?`.

Comment: @Cyrus I use 
servicestatus=$(pgrep -f apollo)
echo $servicestatus
In my script and run "sh filename" output is
15278
Apollo MQTT is Running.
When my apollo service is stopped.

Comment: I suggest to ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: It could be possible that the service is not honoring the stop request, or it is stuck. Does this service supports a status command? Something like `service apollo status`. Asking on superuser seems like proper step now. Give reference to this question on that. I have voted for migration to superuser.

Comment: @anishsane service apollo status shows service is stopped.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't know about "Super User"

Comment: @Cyrus When I run my Apollo Service using "service apollo-broker-service start" command output is "apollo-broker-service is now running (23030)" after that when i run "pidof -x "java"" command it gives the output "23030" ??

Comment: Post output of `ps -ef | grep [2]3030`.

Comment: @Cyrus When i run "ps -ef | grep [2]4628" it gives the output
"root      24628      1 17 17:36 pts/0    00:00:20 java -ea -server -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dapollo.home=/opt/apollo -Dapollo.base=/var/lib/mqtt -classpath /opt/apollo/lib/apollo-boot.jar org.apache.activemq.apollo.boot.Apollo /var/lib/mqtt/lib\;/opt/apollo/lib org.apache.activemq.apollo.cli.Apollo run"

Comment: @Cyrus apollo-broker-service is now running (24628)

Comment: Okay. What is now output of `pgrep -f apollo && echo running || echo stopped`?

Comment: @Cyrus "echo $(pgrep -f apollo)" show the output "24628 26717
Apollo MQTT is Running."

Comment: Two pids? Post output of `ps -ef | grep -e [2]3030 -e [2]6717`.

Comment: @Cyrus Two pids because of when I run "ps -ef | grep apollo" it gives me the two rows like this first one is "root      24628      1  2 17:36 ?        00:00:58 java -ea -server -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dapollo.home=/opt/apollo -Dapollo.base=/var/lib/mqtt -classpath /opt/apollo/lib/apollo-boot.jar org.apache.activemq.apollo.boot.Apollo /var/lib/mqtt/lib\;/opt/apollo/lib org.apache.activemq.apollo.cli.Apollo run" and second one is "root      26967  26577  0 18:21 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apollo"

Comment: With running service, upload file.txt somewhere and post its link here: `ps -ef > file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this;

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i apollo | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
 echo "Apollo MQTT is Running."
 exit 0
else
 echo "Apollo MQTT is Stopped."
 exit 2
fi
```

Comment: above code always shows Apollo MQTT is Running. If service is running and stop both cases.

Comment: Why do you need this entire pipeline, when you can simply use `pgrep`, or a bit worse case, [`if ps -ef | grep -iq "[a]pollo"; then ... fi`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#wc) or worst case, `if ps -ef | grep -i "[a]pollo" &>/dev/null; then ... fi`

Comment: could you provide ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i apollo

Comment: try; if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "org.apache.activemq.apollo.cli.Apollo run" | wc -l) > 0 ))

Comment: @M.Dogru When I start apollo and run "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i apollo" output is "root      12990      1 99 12:48 pts/0    00:00:19 java -ea -server -Xmx1G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dapollo.home=/opt/apollo -Dapollo.base=/var/lib/mqtt -classpath /opt/apollo/lib/apollo-boot.jar org.apache.activemq.apollo.boot.Apollo /var/lib/mqtt/lib\;/opt/apollo/lib org.apache.activemq.apollo.cli.Apollo run" When i stop apollo run "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i apollo" output is blank.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your have neglected one issue. The process is a java instance, and the `pidof` of your program is that of the java instance. `pidof` does not know anything about `apollo`, since it is like an argument for him.

I will recommend the solution from muzido

Comment: You are right. My apollo service using java instance. But My question is that it always use java instance? If i check pidof -x "java" currently it is running perfect but in future apollo always use java instance?